# ASP:MENU On click open submenu

Tags: asp.net, aspmenu

I have the following ASP:Menu

```
<asp:Menu id="menu_mymenu" runat="server"  OnMenuItemClick="menu_mymenu_Click">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="menu_1" Value ="menu_1">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="menu_a" Value="menu_a" />
            <asp:MenuItem Text="menu_b" Value="menu_b"/>
        </asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>                                                               
</asp:Menu>
```

On mouse over it displays submenus menu_a and menu_b.  I would like the onclick on menu_1 to display the submenus menu_a and menu_b in the same way without posting back.  Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is not something that is particularly easy to do and may be a bit hacky.  I've seen a lot of suggestions of trying to use a treeview instead of the menu control.  Anyway here are some resources I found and a solution that appears may do the trick:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1250342.aspx

[Is it possible to force a menu popout to trigger on click instead of mouseover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408250/is-it-possible-to-force-a-menu-popout-to-trigger-on-click-instead-of-mouseover)

If it is absolutely necessary to have this be on click then it would be worth looking into a solution that fits your needs.  In this case I would recommend looking into a treeview or looking at a purely css / javascript solution.

Hopefully this gets you down the right path!

Comment: Thanks for the links.  It looks like if I want to get it to work it is gonna be a hacky solution.  I may look into a different menu system.

Answer (score 0):

I have customized as per the requirement; below is the link for complete solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60986351/3099784

Comment: you need to rephrase your answer so that people understand it quickly